# Disable ddl change event from javascript in special case

Tags: javascript, asp.net

There are two radiobuttons and a dropdownlist. If `rad1` is checked and dropdownlist value is changed than perform dropdown change event. If `rad2` is checked than disable change event (not dropdownlist).

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radNew" runat="server" Text="New" GroupName="radSelect" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radExisting" runat="server" Text="Existing" GroupName="radSelect" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" 
        runat="server"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        EnableViewState="true"
        onClick="return ddlClick();"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>Val1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Val2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Val3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function ddlClick() {
    if(document.getElementById('<%=radNew.ClientID%>').checked){
        return false;
    }
}
```

It is still performing change event of dropdownlist on `rad2` selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *Alternate 1*

We need to overwrite the `onchange` event of the *dropdown*, then based on the conditions execute the required.

```
If the RadioButton is selected then 
   doYourStuff; 
   return false;
else
   Call __doPostBack function on the Dropdown
```

***Sample Code***

Default.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:RadioButton ID="radNew" runat="server" Text="New" GroupName="radSelect" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radExisting" runat="server" Text="Existing" GroupName="radSelect" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>Val1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Val2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Val3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lbl" Text=""></asp:Label>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('<%=ddlType.ClientID%>').onchange = function () {
        if (document.getElementById('<%=radNew.ClientID%>').checked) {
            document.getElementById('<%=lbl.ClientID%>').textContent = "From js";
            return false;
        } else {
            setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlType\',\'\')', 0);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl.Text = "From the server";
}
```

---

### *Alternate 2*

Rather than overwriting the `onchange` event of the *dropdown*, add your conditions to the default `dropdown onchange` event.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
    onchange="if(!ddlCheck()){return false;}" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>Val1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Val2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Val3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ddlCheck() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%=radNew.ClientID%>').checked) {
            document.getElementById('<%=lbl.ClientID%>').textContent = "From js";
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

After loading the above to browser *dropdown* would be like

```
<select name="ddlType" onchange="if(!ddlCheck()){console.log(&#39;to&#39;);return false;};
    setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ddlType\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ddlType">
```

So first our condition would be checked and based on the condition it would do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of the ***enableDDLHandler*** radio button if it's **checked** or not. If checked then ***onchange*** of studentDDL do your task. If not checked then the code inside if won't execute.

**Bingo.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Bingo.aspx.cs" Inherits="RadioButtonChanged.Bingo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var ddl = document.getElementById("studentDDL");
            ddl.onchange = function () {
                var radioChecked = document.getElementById("enableDDLHandler");
                if (radioChecked.checked) {
                    document.getElementById("tongo").innerHTML = "Great!!!";
                }
            };
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Enable : <asp:RadioButton GroupName="Check" ID="enableDDLHandler" runat="server"  />
        Disable : <asp:RadioButton GroupName="Check" ID="disableDDLHandler" runat="server" />

        <asp:DropDownList ID="studentDDL" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Bill</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Mark</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Steve</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Linus</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="tongo" runat="server" Text="Nothing" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have already done this. But I want it to be done on client side only.

Comment: @Ami, See the updated answer. The checking is now handled on client side.